# Accessing Layers Through an API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, android, google

So, I have reason to believe that this information is not available. Nonetheless, it involves using Android, and preferably the Google Maps API (though other maps may have APIs which supply this data, so I'm open-minded).

Here is my goal:

1. Generate a random geospatial coordinate confined to a certain radius of lat/lon (should be easy).
2. Validate that location, using layering of some API, to determine that it does not require going in the middle of a road, in a body of water, or on private (or otherwise restricted) areas in order to be adjacent to it (within the margin of error of GPS).
3. If 2 returns invalid, repeat until a coordinate is set.

Now, clearly some companies have access to detailed information about locations (such as Google), but it doesn't appear that they make this information available to developers, having it restricted as a company secret. Does anyone have a workaround?